# Starting gnome-terminal with tuple list arguments

Tags: python, console, gnome

There have been numerous questions about this topic, but I reassure you, non of them seemed to work for me. From Python script A.py, I want to open another python script, B.py, in new window, passing through some arguments:

```
ListA = [('192.168.2.1', '192.168.2.8'), ('192.168.2.3', '192.168.2.5'), ('192.168.2.8', '192.168.2.4')]
Interface = "wlan0"
```

Normally, I would pass them through via the commend-line:
B.py -i Interface -p ListA

But at the moment I am having some trouble with passing them through, this is what I've tried:

```
import subprocess, shlex, os, sys
subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('gnome-terminal -x bash "' + os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'B.py') + ' -i ' + Interface + ' -p "' + str(ListA) + '""'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and:

```
subprocess.Popen(['gnome-terminal', '-x', '"bash', '-c', os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'B.py'), '-i', Interface, '-p', '"' + str(ListenPipes) + '""'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I got multiple errors throwing 'invalid syntax', 'End Of Line while scanning string literal'

B.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print 'Specify all arguments: B.py -i <Interface> -p <Pipe tuple list [(StartPipe, EndPipe), ..]>'
        sys.exit()
    interface = 'wlan0'
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"hi:p:",["interface","pipes"])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        print 'B.py -i <Interface> -p <Pipe tuple list [(StartPipe, EndPipe), ..]>'
        sys.exit()
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            print 'usage: B.py -i <Interface> -p <Pipe tuple list [(StartPipe, EndPipe), ..]>'
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-i", "--interface"):
            interface = re.compile('\033\[\d+(?:;\d+)?m').sub('',arg) #Remove bash colors
        elif opt in ("-p", "--pipes"):
            ListenPipes = ast.literal_eval(arg)
```

I just cant get my script to work, any ideas will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first (maybe silly) idea was to create a tempfile from A.py, write there a Bash script to run B.py with all its arguments, add +X flag and spawn gnome-terminal with tempfile as an argument to run. Is this sollution good enough for you?

Comment: Thanks, its indeed a solution but I would like to keep it clean and not write from A.py a bashscript to execute B.py with its appropriate arguments, and then running the bashfile within a new terminal. I would like to open B.py in a new terminal, with the arguments, directly from A.py, which must be possible with the subprocess library. If there won't be any other solution then I 'll mark yours as the solution. Thanks for the idea!